# Create publish package on TFS build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created service using ASP.Net MVC5 and I want that TFS building would create publish folder for the project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in the build definition the **/p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package** values in "MSBuild arguments" parameter.

Comment: But if I don't want to deploy, but just to  have publish package in tsame location as my other built projects, would this line be rigth to append?